# Can non-blocking sockets be used with epoll's level triggered mode?

Tags: sockets, epoll, epollet

Currently I have a server application which supports multiple client sessions. Server is running with epoll's edge triggered mode. The sockets which are used inside the server are all non-blocking in nature.
The main epoll loop looks something like this,

```
n = epoll_wait()
iterate over n
  if event is epollin(assume client has written some data)
    while(1)
      drain the buffer untill you get EAGAIN
      break
```

Problem here arises when the data continuously flowing over the buffer and buffer never drains. The other sessions does not get a chance to be entertained by the server.
Because of this possible starvation to other clients, I am thinking of using level triggered mode which allows server to entertain all the active sessions in a round robin way.
Can I just use level triggered mode by removing "EPOLLET" from the subscribed event and read buffer data once(like, in LT mode)?
Any comments/references are appreciated.
Thanks !

Comment: I think you can. I would normally use the default (level-triggered) mode myself. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I tried it and it works as expected for me at least.